# How to properly handle subscriptions depending on property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, listener, publish-subscribe, react-props

I have a global service `widgetService` which holds data for a number of widgets, each identified by a `widgetID`. Each widget's data can change at any time. I want to display a widget with a React component, say `WidgetReactComponent`.

The react component shall take a widget ID as property and get the information to display from the widget service. A widget's data can be queried from the widget service with the method `getWidgetData(widgetID)`. And in order to be able to publish data changes, it also offers two methods: `addListenerForWidget(widgetID, listener)` and `removeListenerForWidget(widgetID, listener)`.

When assuming that the property is set once and never changed, this can be achieved like this, following React's recommendations:

```js
class WidgetReactComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: widgetService.getWidgetData(this.props.widgetID)
        };
        this._onDataChange = this._onDataChange.bind(this);
    }

    _onDataChange(newData) {
        this.setState({data: newData});
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // React documentation: "This method is a good place to set up any subscriptions."
        widgetService.addListenerForWidget(this.props.widgetID, this._onDataChange);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // React documentation: "Perform any necessary cleanup in this method, such as [...] cleaning up any subscriptions that were created in componentDidMount()."
        widgetService.removeListenerForWidget(this.props.widgetID, this._onDataChange);
    }

    render() {
        return <div className="Widget">{this.state.data.stuff}</div>;
    }
}
```

The component may then be used like this:

```
<ReactWidgetComponent widgetID={17} />
```

However, the `widgetID` property may change at any time, and the component has to handle this in order to function properly under all circumstances. By react's recommendation, this should be handled by setting the state based on properties using the `static getDerivedStateFromProps` function. But since it is static, I do not have access to the component and cannot change the listeners accordingly.

One way to work around this would be to store the `widgetID` in the state, and then use the lifecycle method `componentDidUpdate` to detect the change, like this:

```js
constructor() {
    super();
    this._onDataChange = this._onDataChange.bind(this);
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
    return {
        widgetID: nextProps.widgetID,
        data: widgetService.getWidgetData(nextProps.widgetID)
    };
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.widgetID !== this.state.widgetID) {
        widgetService.removeListenerForWidget(prevState.widgetID, this._onDataChange);
        widgetService.addListenerForWidget(this.state.widgetID, this._onDataChange);
    }
}
```

However, `componentDidUpdate` won't be called when `shouldComponentUpdate` returns `false`. This doesn't feel like a safe way of doing this. Also I believe the listeners will be wrong for the entire timespan between the property change and the update's completion. How could I safely implement this?

Comment: You don't want sCU return true when `widgetId` updates or say you have some manual optimizations turns it to false?

Comment: I'm also a bit curious since you're using React@16.3, why not use the [createContext API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) as a default subscription mechanism?

Comment: You have a `_onDataChange` method, but you set the callback of the widget listener to `this._onPartyDataChange` Also, as Xlee mentioned, `createContext` api is great for this.

Comment: have you considered using something like [redux](https://redux.js.org/) to manage the application state? It would then be trivial to synchronize the widgets with the data

Comment: I don't have a reason to have sCu return false atm, but I don't want to rely on it. I'll have a look at contexts later, which look promising on a first glance. The `_onPartyDataChange` is just a typing mistake while creating the mcve. I have considered redux for the future, but wanted to keep it simple for now as the whole React infrastructure is new to me and I'm doing baby steps

Comment: I _could_ rewrite my code to either use the new context api or something like redux, but I'd like to a) not store my business data in react components (context api), b) not store my business data in an opinionated way (redux, plain classes with listeners should work fine and are versatile and understandable), and c) not bring a framework on board to solve a seemingly unrelated problem. Thanks for the suggestions so far, though I will work around the problem until I find a direct solution to my problem at hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store `widgetID` in state, you can compare `prevProps` with `this.props`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevProps.widgetID !== this.props.widgetID) {
    widgetService.removeListenerForWidget(prevProps.widgetID, this._onDataChange);
    widgetService.addListenerForWidget(this.props.widgetID, this._onDataChange);
  }
}
```

You will also need to add the listener in `componentDidMount` as `componentDidUpdate` is not called on first rendering:

```
componentDidMount() {
  widgetService.addListenerForWidget(this.props.widgetID, this._onDataChange);
}
```

Regarding your concerns:

> componentDidUpdate won't be called when shouldComponentUpdate returns false

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate):

> Use shouldComponentUpdate() to let React know if a component’s output is not affected by the current change in state or props.

So if you decided to not update the component when `this.props.widgetID` changes, then you are violating the assumption/purpose of `shouldComponentUpdate` and should not expect your widget listener to be updated.

A lot of things will not work as intended if you misuse `shouldComponentUpdate` anyway (eg. component not updated to reflect new data), so relying on an API being used correctly as per official docs is a necessity to achieve simplicity, rather than something to be avoided.

> the listeners will be wrong for the entire timespan between the property change and the update's completion

By this logic, when you update some displayed data in an event handler, you can also claim that the data displayed is wrong for the entire timespan between the event and the re-rendering. You can even claim that your text editor is displaying the wrong data between the time you press a keyboard key and rendering of the key on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of comparing the widgetID via props directly. I already added the listener in `componentDidMount`. My concerns regarding `shouldComponentUpdate` seem to be resolved/irrelevant following your explanation. Regarding the timespan the listeners might be wrong: I'm not worried about data being "delayed", but rather about possible race conditions where the widgetID gets changed, the new widget gets new data before the listener is set up, and that causes "stuck" data. However, that concern is also irrelevant if I just manually pull new data once after adjusting the listeners.

Comment: I'll accept your answer later after trying it out if no other miraculously superior answer pops up

Comment: Remember that JS is single-threaded. The rendering of the new widget will be followed by the remaining lifecycle methods (including `componentDidUpdate`) immediately, so if the new widget gets new data in between that timeframe, React will likely queue it after the lifecycle methods (i.e. after the listener updates) rather than transferring control to the event handler midway through. I don't know how your widget data updates, but if it's in response to an UI event, the UI thread is blocked during the lifecycle processing so such scenario will not happen. It might be different for React Fiber.

Comment: the data changes from incoming websocket messages for me